# C# Mouse Tracking Drawing Odd Behavior

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, drawing, mouse

I've just made some simple code to track the mouse offset from where Mouse Down to its current position on Mouse Move within a PictureBox. I'm outputting the difference to a label and it works fine.

So say I mousedown at X: 20 Y: 20 then move mouse left by 5. My result is X: 15 Y:20.

Now the issue is when I take these results (diffX and diffY) and add them to an integer (testOne and testTwo). The result is exponentially different.

Most relevant is that when I keep the mouse in the same position without moving it but just holding the button. The results continue to increase.

I have reduced my problem to the following code:

```
Point startPoint = new Point();
bool dragging = false;

int testOne = 30;
int testTwo = 30;

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (dragging)
    {
        int diffX = (pictureBox1.PointToClient(e.Location).X - startPoint.X);
        int diffY = (pictureBox1.PointToClient(e.Location).Y - startPoint.Y);

        label9.Text = diffX.ToString();   //Works, shows desired result
        label10.Text = diffY.ToString();  //also works fine

        testOne = (testOne + diffX); //Issue here
        testTwo = (testTwo + diffY); //and here

        label11.Text = (testOne).ToString(); //Unexpected results output
        label12.Text = (testTwo).ToString(); 
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (!dragging) //Incase the mouse down was repeating, it's not
    {
        startPoint = pictureBox1.PointToClient(e.Location);
        dragging = true;
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (dragging)
        dragging = false;
}
```

I'm using C# WinForms in VS 2008, Framework 3.5

any insight would be great, maybe this is a bug or I've simply overlooked something simple. Any ideas or if you can re-produce.

Cheers

Craig

Comment: Also, there's no threads or loops in my code.

Comment: Do you have issue with how often MouseMove events are fired OR with value that you are calculating? Sum(mouseOffset) does not sound like very useful value by itself...

Comment: OT but judging from your code, and if this is for _drawing_, add the drag-points to a list, instead of drawing on the control directly. This allows easy implementation of undo/redo drawing operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though you are subtracting the current point from the start point, not the last point. Set startPoint to the current point at the end of your mousemove function.

```
startPoint = pictureBox1.PointToClient(e.Location);
```

Comment: No worries... I seem to remember having a similar problem writing a paint program in MS QuickBASIC on the mac a number of years ago...

Answer (score 0):

Whe you don't move mouse you should not be getting MouseMove events... Also clicking mouse button will send you MouseMove. In genral MouseMove is send whenever it seems practical and you should be ready to handle 0 movements too.

The value of testOne and testTwo measures "Sum of all mouse movements"  which will grow as long as mouse offset (diffX/Y) is positive (essentially it is integral of mose movements). What your expectations for this values?